# Проблема с загрузкой пакета на Packagist

Tags: php, github, packagist

Создал пустой репозиторий на GitHub. Сделал push проекта[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На Packagist  вставил ссылку на свой репозиторий, но при проверке ругается на файл .json[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл лежит в папке monolog[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package

Comment: у вас в композере не описан source поле, в котором должена быть ссылка на репозиторий тип и ветка

Comment: а стоп, у вас в композере  "name": "sergey/monolog", а вы Road-To-The-Dream/monlogger

Comment: надо поменять поле name в композере на Road-To-The-Dream/monlogger

Comment: вообще для простоты попробуйте сделать по аналогии https://github.com/weaverryan/derp-dangerzone